# Separating numbers to 2 arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a question about Java. I made this code to separate negative and positive numbers into 2 arrays and after that to print them. But all the time when I start that I have an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at mypackages.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:26)
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
package mypackages;

public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

   int counterNeg = 0;
   int counterPoz = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
        if (array[i] < 0){
            counterNeg++;
        } else if (array[i] > 0){
            counterPoz++;
        }
    }


    int[] arrayNeg = new int[counterNeg];
    int[] arrayPoz = new int[counterPoz];

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] < 0){
            arrayNeg[j] = array[j];
        } else if (array[j] > 0){
            arrayPoz[j] = array[j];
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger and debug the code step by step to understand what is happening.

Comment: It looks obvious to me that in general either `arrayPoz` or `arrayNeg` won't  have the same length as `array`, and hence your second loops will cause this error.

Comment: Your `counterNeg` and `counterPoz` is always smaller than `array.length`. Thus you got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the arrays `arrayNeg` and `arrayPoz` by using the index that goes up to `array.length - 1` causing a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds because both arrays are smaller than the original one.

Solution: keep track of where to insert the numbers in to the two downstream arrays:

```
int[] arrayNeg = new int[counterNeg];
int[] arrayPoz = new int[counterPoz];
int arrayNegCounter = 0;
int arrayPozCounter = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[j] < 0){
        arrayNeg[arrayNegCounter] = array[j];
        arrayNegCounter++;
    } else if (array[j] > 0){
        arrayPoz[arrayPozCounter] = array[j];
        arrayPozCounter++;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers to this question definitely solve the problem, but it's worth noting that this is the kind of problem you may want to use Java's streams to solve, instead of implementing it yourself:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map =
    Arrays.stream(array)
          .filter(i -> i != 0)
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i > 0));
List<Integer> positives = map.get(Boolean.TRUE);
List<Integer> negatives = map.get(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int a = 0, b = 0, j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[j] < 0){
        arrayNeg[a++] = array[j];
    } else {
        arrayPoz[b++] = array[j];
    }
}
```

The problem lies from using j as your index to access arrayNeg and arrayPoz, remember that the sizes of each array is not equal.